# Geofence PendingIntent with extras

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-geofence

Here is the problem:

**Service that add geofences:**

```
public class GeofenceService extends Service implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationClient.OnAddGeofencesResultListener, LocationClient.OnRemoveGeofencesResultListener {
     ...

            @Override
                public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onConnected");
                    switch (action){
                        case ADD:
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected ADD");
                            locationClient.addGeofences(geofencesToAdd, getPendingIntent(), this);
                            break;
                        case REMOVE:
                            Log.d(TAG, "onConnected REMOVE");
                            locationClient.removeGeofences(geofencesToRemove, this);
                            break;
                    }
                }

                private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(){
                    Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TransitionsIntentService.class);
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEALS, deals);
                    return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                }
    ...
}
```

As you can see there is Intent which pass some data and starts `TransitionIntentService`:

```
public class TransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

   ... 
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        deals = (ArrayList<Deal>) intent.getSerializableExtra(GeofenceService.EXTRA_DEALS); //THIS CAN BE NULL

        int transitionType = LocationClient.getGeofenceTransition(intent);

        List<Geofence> triggeredGeofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent); //THIS CAN BE NULL
        List<String> triggeredIds = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (Geofence geofence : triggeredGeofences) {
            Log.d("GEO", "onHandle:" + geofence.getRequestId());
            processGeofence(geofence, transitionType);
            triggeredIds.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }

    ...
}
```

If I try to putExtra(..., deals) in `getPendingIntent` method I'v got `List<Geofence> triggeredGeofences = LocationClient.getTriggeringGeofences(intent) == NULL`.

If I don't pass extra everything works fine.

How can I pass my extra and still get extra from `LocationClient`?

Comment: Is only `triggeredGeofences` null, or `deals` too in `onHandleIntent`?

Comment: If I pass Deal objects as extra then deals not null. If I don't then triggeredGeofences not null. Also, I can pass String object as extra and everithing will be fine. The problem apears when I try to pass my own Serializable Deal Object

Comment: even I have this issue, did you resolve it by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I was confronted to the exact same symptoms and problems. Basically, it seems the `GeofenceEvent` cannot coexist with a `Serializable` extra in the intent. The only solution I found was to flatten the serializable object and use a separate extra with a simple data type for each field instead, as in this simple example:

Object to transfer via intent:

```
public class MyObject {
  public String stringfield;
  public int intField;

  public MyObject fromIntent(Intent intent) {
    stringField = intent.getStringExtra("stringField");
    intField = intent.getIntExtra("intField", -1);
    return this;
  }

  public MyObject toIntent(Intent intent) {
    intent.putExtra("stringField", stringField);
    intent.putExtra("intField", intField);
    return this;
  }
}
```

Creating and populating the intent:

```
MyObject obj = ...;
Intent intent = ...;
myObject.toIntent(intent);
```

Extracting data from the received intent:

```
Intent intent = ...;
MyObject obj = new MyObject().fromIntent(intent);
```

This is a bit cumbersome, but it's the only way I could get it to work. I can now extract both the GeofenceEvent data and my custom data from the same intent.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `GeofenceEvent` cannot coexist with a `Serializable` extra in the intent.

The solution I found was to make the **passing object** become **static**. In the `IntentService` class, access the static object directly.

For example,

GeofenceService.java

```
public class GeofenceService extends Service implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, ...

{

     ...

     public static ArrayList<Deal> extraDeals;

     ...

}
```

TransitionsIntentService.java

```
public class TransitionsIntentService extends IntentService {

    ... 

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        ...

        deals = GeofenceService.extraDeals;

        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not Expert But This May Helps You

in Your code

```
return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

replace with this

```
return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

For those looking at this and have the .putExtra methods before attaching to PendingIntent, the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` is important, so try that before moving on to another solution.